# Aframe ar.js canvas Context with angular 6

Tags: canvas, aframe, ar.js

Do anyone now how you get the context of the a-frame aer.js canvas? in the dev mode of google chrome i can see a-canvas class but no id to get the context by id.

```
<canvas class="a-canvas" data-aframe-canvas="true" width="1920" height="1440" style="width: 1536px; height: 1152px;"></canvas>
```

I would like to have something like var `ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');`
I am using a-frame with angular 6. When I do it with

```
const canvas2: HTMLCanvasElement =  document.querySelector(".a-canvas");
const ctx=canvas2.getContext('2d');
```

the const `ctx` is always `null`

Answer (score 0):

a-frame has a `webgl` context, not a `2d` one. You can grab the `webgl` context with:

```
canvas.getContext('webgl')
```

---

You can grab the `a-frame` canvas by its class

```
<canvas class="a-canvas" ....>
```

..

```
var canvas = document.querySelector(".a-canvas")
```

---

`ar.js` creates a `<video>` element with the camera feed, you can simply do

```
var feed = document.querySelector("video")
```

---

Make sure that the scene is fully loaded when you try to access it. From the [docs](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/scene.html):

```
// scene - scene reference (this.el.sceneEl, queryselector(a-scene)
scene.addEventListener('loaded', (e)=> {
  // code here
}
```

(or just set a timer)

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/21aomjny/).

Comment: Thank you I could solve the problem with this post.https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/issues/341